# WordPress Visual Composer accordion won't load with css

Tags: wordpress, visual-c++, accordion

When I use the Visual Composer WordPress plugin everything works great. Except for the accordion, Pageable container and some other elements. When I add these elements they do show on my page, however is seems that the CSS is missing.

I've tried to disable all other plugins, nothing changed.

Theme code for showing the content:

```
$post = get_post();
$content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
echo $content;
```

Screenshot WordPress backend:
[WP Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kap6p.png)

Screenshot frontend & console: [frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK7i5.png)

Please note: other elements do work perfect, animations work, grid building work and more.
Also note: there are no errors showing up in the console.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Note: when downgrading to Visual Composer 4.2 the accordion works fine. However I do not want to keep my site on such an old version. Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with the latest version (5.4.7) and a custom theme.
I've noticed the body has lost the class `wpb-js-composer`, required to make visual composer works correctly.
If I add this class manually everything works fine.

I'm investigating on why this class has not been applied on the body by WP Backery (Visual composer)

**EDIT**
After a brief search I've found I forgot to add the [body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function to my template.
Before:

```
<body>
```

After:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Now Visual composer accordions, tabs, and other elements works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

this is plugin, if we want to change css then go to this step   plugin->editor->select visual composer->go to the css file....then whatever u want to change in your css file...

i hope it will help you...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. But not, this is not what I'm looking for. Visual Composer usually shows an accordion with a standart styling. This styling is completely missing aswel as the complete functionality of the accordion.